# Como consumir os dados de uma api para mostrar no front-end utilizando páginas razor?

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

Sou iniciante em desenvolvimento .net core e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que consome dados de uma api e mostra para os usuários, porém não consigo converter JSON em OBJECT e amarzenar tudo em uma IEnumerable.

Estou utilizando o REFIT para fazer as requisições HTTP.

Classe de modelo:

```
  public class Json
  {
    [JsonProperty("Message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Global")]
    public Global Global { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Countries")]
    public Country[] Countries { get; set; }
  }

  public class Global
  {
    [JsonProperty("NewConfirmed")]
    public long NewConfirmed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TotalConfirmed")]
    public long TotalConfirmed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("NewDeaths")]
    public long NewDeaths { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TotalDeaths")]
    public long TotalDeaths { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("NewRecovered")]
    public long NewRecovered { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TotalRecovered")]
    public long TotalRecovered { get; set; }
  }
  public class Country
  {
    [JsonProperty("Country")]
    public string CountryCountry { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CountryCode")]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Slug")]
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("NewConfirmed")]
    public long NewConfirmed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TotalConfirmed")]
    public long TotalConfirmed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("NewDeaths")]
    public long NewDeaths { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TotalDeaths")]
    public long TotalDeaths { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("NewRecovered")]
    public long NewRecovered { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TotalRecovered")]
    public long TotalRecovered { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Date")]
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Premium")]
    public Premium Premium { get; set; }
  }

  public class Premium
  {
  }
```

Classe IndexModel:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
  {
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    public IEnumerable<Json> Cities { get; private set; } = new List<Json>();

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
      _logger = logger;
    }

    public async void OnGet()
    {
      try
      {
        var city = RestService.For<IJsonApiService>("https://api.covid19api.com/summary");
        Cities = (IEnumerable<Json>)await city.GetCity().ConfigureAwait(false);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        _logger.LogInformation("Erro na requisição http: " + e.Message);
      }
    }
  }
```

Interface IJsonApiService:

```
public interface IJsonApiService
{
   [Get("")]
   Task<Json> GetCity();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Observação pertinente***: essa [api](/questions/tagged/api) retorna um objeto que em seus membros possui outras objetos e um deles é lista de cidades, então, não tem como retornar por essa [api](/questions/tagged/api) o que está perguntado e resolvi colocar o exemplo cabível mediante ao retorna correta dessa [api](/questions/tagged/api).

---

O layout das classes base para carregar as informações do [json](/questions/tagged/json) enviados pela requisição é o seguinte:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Global Global { get; set; }
    public Country[] Countries { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class Global
{
    public int NewConfirmed { get; set; }
    public int TotalConfirmed { get; set; }
    public int NewDeaths { get; set; }
    public int TotalDeaths { get; set; }
    public int NewRecovered { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecovered { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    [JsonProperty("Country")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
    public int NewConfirmed { get; set; }
    public int TotalConfirmed { get; set; }
    public int NewDeaths { get; set; }
    public int TotalDeaths { get; set; }
    public int NewRecovered { get; set; }
    public int TotalRecovered { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Premium Premium { get; set; }
}

public class Premium
{
}
```

e para trabalhar com [refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit) precisa ser criado uma [interface](/questions/tagged/interface) para consumo da [api](/questions/tagged/api) seguinte forma:

```
public interface IGetRootobject
{
    [Get("")]
    Task<Rootobject> GetAsync();
}
```

e por fim para utilizar todo código anterior e consumir por definitivo a [api](/questions/tagged/api):

```
var create = RestService.For<IGetRootobject>("https://api.covid19api.com/summary");
var result = create.GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
// ou var result = await create.GetAsync();
```

sendo que os valores de `result` é o retorno da [api](/questions/tagged/api).

<sup>***Referencia:*** [refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit)</sup>

Comment: Se o retorno da var result é o da api, então a result contém json? Como posso então transformar esse json em object para mostrar no front-end?

Comment: o result é a classe no meu exemplo `Rootobject` que no seu caso é `Json` (esse nome não é bom troque), no retorno já é o objeto pronto montando com as informações @EduardoNogueira pegue esse código e teste pra você ver que na variável `result` tem todas as informações

Comment: Implementei aqui. Agora eu preciso percorrer esse Rootobject para conseguir pegar os dados, mas antes eu preciso percorrer o Countries. Como faço isso?

Comment: @EduardoNogueira cada pergunta gera uma resposta, se pode criar outra pergunta para essa nova duvida, e outra coisa se essa te respondeu a duvida inicial vote e sinalize como resposta da sua pergunta

Comment: OK. Obrigado pela ajuda.