# Como mostrar os dados no front-end utilizando razor pages?

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core

Sou iniciante em desenvolvimento .net core e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que consome dados de uma api e mostra para os usuários, porém não sei como mostrar os dados no front-end.

Estou utilizando o REFIT para fazer as requisições HTTP.

A api retorna três propriedades e eu preciso percorrer uma delas, pois é a que contém todos os dados que preciso.

Modelo de retorno da api:

```
{
"Message": "",
  "Global": {
    "NewConfirmed": 539275,
    "TotalConfirmed": 83951583,
    "NewDeaths": 9422,
    "TotalDeaths": 1827430,
    "NewRecovered": 278963,
    "TotalRecovered": 47278729
  },
  "Countries": [
    {
      "Country": "Afghanistan",
      "CountryCode": "AF",
      "Slug": "afghanistan",
      "NewConfirmed": 0,
      "TotalConfirmed": 51526,
      "NewDeaths": 0,
      "TotalDeaths": 2191,
      "NewRecovered": 0,
      "TotalRecovered": 41727,
      "Date": "2021-01-02T23:29:42Z",
      "Premium": {
        
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Classe de modelo:

```
public class Rootobject
  {
    [JsonProperty("Message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Global")]
    public Global Global { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Countries")]
    public Country[] Countries { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
  }

  public class Global
  {
    [JsonProperty("NewConfirmed")]
    public int NewConfirmed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TotalConfirmed")]
    public int TotalConfirmed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("NewDeaths")]
    public int NewDeaths { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TotalDeaths")]
    public int TotalDeaths { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("NewRecovered")]
    public int NewRecovered { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TotalRecovered")]
    public int TotalRecovered { get; set; }
  }
  public class Country
  {
    [JsonProperty("Country")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("CountryCode")]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Slug")]
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("NewConfirmed")]
    public int NewConfirmed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TotalConfirmed")]
    public int TotalConfirmed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("NewDeaths")]
    public int NewDeaths { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TotalDeaths")]
    public int TotalDeaths { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("NewRecovered")]
    public int NewRecovered { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("TotalRecovered")]
    public int TotalRecovered { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Premium")]
    public Premium Premium { get; set; }
  }

  public class Premium
  {
  }
```

Classe PageModel:

```
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    public IEnumerable<IGetRootobject> Cities { get; private set; } = new List<IGetRootobject>();
    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
      _logger = logger;
    }

    public async void OnGet()
    {
      try
      {
        var create = RestService.For<IGetRootobject>("https://api.covid19api.com/summary");
        var result = await create.GetAsync(); // ou var result = create.GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        var res = result.Global.NewConfirmed;
        _logger.LogInformation(res.ToString());
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        _logger.LogInformation("Erro na requisição http: " + e.Message);
      }
    }
```

Página Razor:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xxl-3 col-lg-4">
    <div class="card bg-primary text-white mb-4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <div class="mr-3">
            <div class="text-white-75 small">@city</div>
            <div class="text-lg font-weight-bold">$40,000</div>
          </div>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none"
            stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
            class="feather feather-calendar feather-xl text-white-50">
            <rect x="3" y="4" width="18" height="18" rx="2" ry="2"></rect>
            <line x1="16" y1="2" x2="16" y2="6"></line>
            <line x1="8" y1="2" x2="8" y2="6"></line>
            <line x1="3" y1="10" x2="21" y2="10"></line>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
        <a class="small text-white stretched-link" href="#">View Report</a>
        <div class="small text-white"><svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-angle-right fa-w-8" aria-hidden="true"
            focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="angle-right" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            viewBox="0 0 256 512" data-fa-i2svg="">
            <path fill="currentColor"
              d="M224.3 273l-136 136c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0l-22.6-22.6c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9l96.4-96.4-96.4-96.4c-9.4-9.4-9.4-24.6 0-33.9L54.3 103c9.4-9.4 24.6-9.4 33.9 0l136 136c9.5 9.4 9.5 24.6.1 34z">
            </path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ao implementar essa solução proposta:

```
public Country[] Countries { get; private set; }
```

consegui armazenar os dados aí e mostrar pela página razor, porém está sendo gerada uma exceção ao executar a aplicação:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object. InfoCovid.Pages.Pages_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml,
> line 9

linha que a exception é gerada:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Countries)
```

Minha página PageModel agora:

```
public async void OnGet()
{
  try
  {
    var create = RestService.For<IGetRootobject>("https://api.covid19api.com/summary");
    var result = await create.GetAsync(); // ou var result = create.GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Countries = result.Countries;
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    _logger.LogInformation("Erro na requisição http: " + e.Message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Qual dado você quer mostrar na tela?

Comment: As contries que a api retorna. Consigo acessar as propriedades Message(que não tem nada) e Global, mas não consigo percorrer a propriedade Contries. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para exibir seguindo a sua última pergunta ([Como consumir os dados de uma api para mostrar no front-end utilizando páginas razor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/488611/como-consumir-os-dados-de-uma-api-para-mostrar-no-front-end-utilizando-p%c3%a1ginas-r)) ao qual deseja imprimir na sua tela somente as cidades siga o exemplo logo abaixo, crie um propriedade publica para que no modelo de negócio tenha acesso a essa propriedade, exemplo

```
public Country[] Countries { get; private set; }
```

e no momento do seu retorno utiliza a atribuição simples:

```
Countries = result.Countries;
```

Código completo:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Refit;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Pages
{
    public class MostrarModel : PageModel
    {
        public Country[] Countries { get; private set; }
        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            var create = RestService.For<IGetRootobject>("https://api.covid19api.com/summary");
            var result = await create.GetAsync();
            Countries = result.Countries;
        }
    }
}
```

e na sua `View` faça um `foreach` em `Model.Countries` que é a propriedade publica, exemplo:

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.MostrarModel


@foreach (var item in Model.Countries)
{
  <div>@item.Name</div>
}
```

O exemplo é fica fácil refletir no seu código é só colocar a propriedade e fazer a iteração na sua `View`.