# Como faço para não precisar ficar fazendo requisição toda hora a api?

Tags: c#, razor, .net-core

Sou iniciante em desenvolvimento .net core e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que consome dados de uma api e mostra para os usuários, porém preciso ficar atualizando o site toda hora e isso demora um pouco.

Existe alguma forma de eu armazenar o retorno da api temporariamente em algum lugar?

Classe PageModel, que faz a requisição a api:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
  public Global Global { get; private set; }
  public Country[] Countries { get; private set; }

  public async Task OnGetAsync()
  {
    try
    {
      var create = RestService.For<IGetRootobject>("https://api.covid19api.com/summary");
      var result = await create.GetAsync(); // ou var result = create.GetAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
      Global = result.Global;
      Countries = result.Countries;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      _logger.LogInformation("Erro na requisição http: " + e.Message);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O mais simples pode ser utilizado o [Cache in-memory in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.2&source=docs) (tradução: Cache na memória) que pode ser configurado em segundos, minutos, dias, etc. a sua permanência na memória da informação, ou seja, conforme a sua necessidade.

Para habilitar esse código no seu projeto no `startup.cs` no método `ConfigureServices` chame o método de extensão `.AddMemoryCache()` com mostrado no código:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMemoryCache(); // adicione essa linha para funciona cache em memoria
    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

com isso agora está habilitado pra ser utilizar nas `Pages Razor` e como está num batalha em algumas perguntas ([1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/488630/como-mostrar-os-dados-no-front-end-utilizando-razor-pages) e [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/488611/como-consumir-os-dados-de-uma-api-para-mostrar-no-front-end-utilizando-p%C3%A1ginas-r)) segue o mesmo exemplo a seguir:

Adicione um propriedade:

```
public IMemoryCache MemoryCache { get; private set; }
```

depois no `construtor` da sua `PageModel` passe a `interface` e atribua a propriedade anteriormente criada para a injeção que é passado no `construtor`:

```
public MostrarModel(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
    MemoryCache = memoryCache;
}
```

a partir disso tem a possibilidade criar *cache* das informações na memória de qualquer tipo e por um simples estrutura de decisão pode buscar o valor no *cache* ou então criar o valor e armazenar no *cache* por uma quantidade de tempo (no caso exemplo logo abaixo no código completo foi adicionado trinta minutos, mas, como já foi relatado por ser configurado dias e horas a sua maneira):

Código final:

```
public class MostrarModel : PageModel
{
    public Country[] Countries { get; private set; }        
    public IMemoryCache MemoryCache { get; private set; } // cache
    public MostrarModel(IMemoryCache memoryCache) // injeção
    {
        MemoryCache = memoryCache; // atribuição
    }
    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        //chave do cache (cada valor armazenado tem a sua) 
        string key = "countries_cache";
        //verificando se o valor está ou não em cache e tomando as medidas
        //dependendo da decisão na estrutura
        if (!MemoryCache.TryGetValue<Country[]>(key, out Country[] values))
        {
            var create = RestService
                .For<IGetRootobject>("https://api.covid19api.com/summary");
            var result = await create.GetAsync();
            Countries = result.Countries;
            //Armazenando em cache
            MemoryCache.Set(key, Countries, System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
        } 
        else
        {
            //recuperando do cache
            Countries = values;
        }
    }
}
```

A outra forma é com [Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.2) que nesse caso é um informação compartilhada em vários servidores que melhora muito o desempenho e escabilidade e sua configuração é parecida com a anterior:

Adicione o método de extensão:

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
```

e no construtor e no código são bem parecidos com o anterior

private readonly IDistributedCache MemoryCache;

```
public MostrarModel(IDistributedCache memoryCache)
{
    MemoryCache = memoryCache;
}
```

e com os métodos `GetAsync` para recuperar e `SetAsync` para gravar o *cache*.

---

Vários tipos ainda existem como:

- [Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
- [Distributed SQL Server Cache](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.2#distributed-sql-server-cache-1)
- [Distributed Redis Cache](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.2#distributed-redis-cache-1)

Comment: Qual seria o mais recomendado? Cache in-memory in ASP.NET Core ou Distributed caching in ASP.NET Core ?

Comment: Pode usar cachê in-memory @eduardonogueira